# How to make an input field appear after making selection using CSS

Tags: css, forms

I would like to edit a form field to remain hidden unless a previous option has been selected.

For Example, in an application there is an option to select how you were referred. If you select option "other", a new field will appear below asking what "other" is.

I have zero experience in javascript/jquery... if it is possible to do this with CSS only that would be great; if not I can just add to the languages I'm learning right now.

Comment: only CSS i don't think so ... as you can read in your question, you are talking about events "if you select" --> "a new field appear" : this is JS, and it's also good to learn it too, as you won't do big things with only HTML/CSS

Comment: Thanks for the advice; its on the table to learn. I'm just literally juggling 4 different languages I'm learning right now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution using a sibling selector (~) and the :checked pseudo selector:

```css
#hidden {
  display: none;
}

#other:checked~#hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>option 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" />
  <label>other</label>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="option" />
  <div id="hidden">
    <span>this is a hidden field</span>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```